# Table format in Hirb for .where Rails 3 queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

I am using http://tagaholic.me/hirb/ to format AR queries in console with pretty, MySQL like table views.

The problem is, that by default Rails 3 .where queries, reaturned as ActiveRecord::Relation arent displayed in a table format. With imported table method everything is formatted properly. How to set default display to table in Hirb for a given object type?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me with hirb version 0.3.5 and Rails 3.0.1.

Check your `~/.irbrc` file doesn't use `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` to determine whether to load Hirb, because Rails 3 no longer sets that. Use this instead:

```
# ~/.irbrc
Hirb.enable if defined?(Rails)
```

If using RVM, add it to your Gemfile to ensure hirb is correctly loaded:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'hirb', :require => nil
```

Comment: It works because it was "fixed" in 0.3.5. Check https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb/issues/closed#issue/22

Answer (score 0):

**Or you can use richrc**
RichRC (Rich Rails Console) is a customization tool for Rails 3 console.

```
sudo gem install richrc hirb wirble
```

make a new alias in ~/.bash_profile

> alias railsc="richrc"
>
> source ~/.bash_profile

insted of rails c 
use:

> railsc

website: [richrc](http://rubydoc.info/gems/richrc/frames)